# what cmd command I can use ANSI formatting for my OSQL output text file?

Tags: sql, batch-file, formatting, osql

I am running OSQL command in .bat file and I am running my SQL script and generating the output in a text file, however the data in the file is scattered and I want to generate the file in the same format as i can generate via SQL Server manually.

I have also tried with .rpt and .txt format but still facing the same issue.

So if anyone can suggest any command or any alternative way, so that I can generate the file same as I am generating manually through SQL server.

Any suggestions or idea is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Show the code that is generating the odd output.

Comment: You need a tool for encoding and call it from cmd.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some options like `-s ","` to separate your columns by a comma. In my following example I am executing a store procedure from command line. e.g :

`osql -E -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON;EXECUTE REPORTDB.[DBO].[SP_LOAD_USERDATA] %date%" -o C:\ADELPHE\OUTPUT_FOLDER\_%date%.txt  -w 700 -s","`

Have a look on this [manual](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162806.aspx).